# Non-callable subclass of a callable class

Tags: python, inheritance, callable

I have a class `A` that is callable. I also have a subclass of `A` called `B` that I want to make not callable. It should raise the normal "not callable" `TypeError` when I try to call it.

```
class A():
    def __call__(self):
        print "I did it"

class B(A):
    def __call__(self):
        raise TypeError("'B' object is not callable")
```

As you can see, my solution right now is to raise a duplicate of the normal `TypeError`. This feels wrong, since I'm just copying the text of a standard python exception. It would be better (in my opinion) if there was a way to mark a subclass as not callable and then have python handle that attribute.

What is the best way to make class `B` not callable, given that it's a subclass of the callable class `A`?

Comment: Hmm. Have you considered the standard [`NotImplementedError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NotImplementedError)?

Comment: You may want to rethink your design. If B doesn't implement a method that A declares, can you really say that B is a kind of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override type creation with Python metaclasses. Here after object creation, I replace parent's `__call__` method with another one throwing an exception:

```
>>> class A(object):
    def __call__(self):
        print 'Called !'


>>> class MetaNotCallable(type):
    @staticmethod
    def call_ex(*args, **kwargs):
            raise NotImplementedError()

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dict):
        obj = super(MetaNotCallable, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, dict)
        obj.__call__ = MetaNotCallable.call_ex # Change method !
        return obj


>>> class B(A):
    __metaclass__ = MetaNotCallable


>>> a = A()
>>> a()
Called !
>>> b = B()
>>> b()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#131>", line 1, in <module>
    b()
  File "<pyshell#125>", line 4, in call_ex
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Why is a metaclass necessary/helpful here?  Seems much easier just to directly define a `__call__` method in `B` that raises the exception.

Comment: The author just did that, so I wanted to propose something else... I agree it may look overkill at first sight, but it exposes advanced Python functionality - and if several classes are concerned, you just set the `__metaclasse__` attribute and you're done - no need to repeat (which is evil!!!).